# Getting DOM element from JavaScript using RichFaces 4

Tags: javascript, dom, richfaces, getelementbyid

I am currently studying a migration to RichFaces 4.
From my JS, I have have to get DOM elements using

```
document.getElementById('myParent:myElement').
```

From the JBoss migration guide, I understood that "document.getElementById" can no longer be used : https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration-CommonComponentsChanges.

**Can somebody explain me why, and how can I (simply) change all my calls to this function - over a thousand - to something else ?**

Thanks.

Comment: I followed your link now...tbh, all I can think to share about this is...bummer !

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you to read this article:
[RichFaces built-in client functions](http://planet.jboss.org/post/richfaces_built_in_client_functions)

To summarize, there are 4 built in function:

1. `#{rich:clientId('id')}`
2. `#{rich:element('id')}`
3. `#{rich:component('id')}`
4. `#{rich:findComponent('id')}`

Explanation:

- The first one permit to convert richfaces id to string.
- The second one is used to `getElementById` (HTML Element)
- The third one is used to `getElementById` (JavaScript Component)
- The last to get value without a call to the managedBean